# Ember and Carrierwave

Tags: ember.js, carrierwave

So when querying the model which returns a carrierwave hash, I'm getting his.get('pic')
"[object Object]" in Ember. So How do I get into the view?

```
{"record":{"id":1234,"first_name":"John","gravepic":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/record/gravepic/13267/IMG_0013.JPG","ios":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/record/gravepic/13267/ios_IMG_0013.JPG"},"thumb":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/record/gravepic/13267/thumb_IMG_0013.JPG"},"small":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/record/gravepic/13267/small_IMG_0013.JPG"},"medium":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/record/gravepic/13267/medium_IMG_0013.JPG"},"large":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/record/gravepic/13267/large_IMG_0013.JPG"}},"eulogy":"FATHER","deceased":true,"gender":"male","photos":[{"accuracy":null,"approval":null,"asset_caption":"","asset_name":null,"assetpic":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/photo/assetpic/270/iccfa_350x200_3.jpg","thumb":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/photo/assetpic/270/thumb_iccfa_350x200_3.jpg"},"small":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/photo/assetpic/270/small_iccfa_350x200_3.jpg"},"medium":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/photo/assetpic/270/medium_iccfa_350x200_3.jpg"},"large":{"url":"http://c185643.r43.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/photo/assetpic/270/large_iccfa_350x200_3.jpg"}},"copyright":null,"coredata_id":null,"created_at":"2013-02-09T10:36:13Z","id":270,"ignore":null,"is_approved":true,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"record_id":"13267","updated_at":"2013-02-09T10:36:13Z","user_id":1},{"accuracy":null,"approval":null,"asset_caption":null,"asset_name":null,"assetpic":{"url":null,"thumb":{"url":null},"small":{"url":null},"medium":{"url":null},"large":{"url":null}},"copyright":null,"coredata_id":null,"created_at":null,"id":null,"ignore":null,"is_approved":true,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"record_id":13267,"updated_at":null,"user_id":null}],"copies":[{"content":null,"created_at":null,"id":null,"is_approved":true,"name":null,"record_id":13267,"summary":null,"updated_at":null,"user_id":null}],}}
```

The next questions will be something  like record.photos.first.medium. 
Or record.gravepic.small

Just not sure how to get to something beyond "object object"

Comment: `[object Object]` means that you're returning a JS Object/hash, you'll need to drill down further to get the url you are looking for. `this.get('gravepic.ios.url')` should return something useful.

Comment: Hey Bradley, thanks for commenting, but all I get is undefined. I was expecting to be able to just add in the properties, but I get nothing. Any good ideas where to go from here?

Comment: Could it be that it isn't working because my model doesn't have it defined. I did try to put gravepic.url: DS.attr('string')  - However that doesn't work. Any help for this?  DS.Store revision 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is still the exact API, but if you want multiple values out of the hash I suggest adding a new `DS.attr` type.

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('json', {
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return Em.isNone(serialized) ? {} : serialized;
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return Em.isNone(deserialized) ? {} : deserialized;
  }
})

App.Something = DS.Model.extend({
  gravepic: DS.attr("json")
})
```

Comment: That is awesome. Just want I needed. Thanks! This should be part of ember data.